# Change color of an instance of a button in CS4 Flash

Tags: flash, button, cs4

I have 2 instances of a button wich is red and has a white label

I have to edit the buttons so one button is red, and the other is green

I was doing this, but when applied Also the title of label goes green instead of being white...

```
var btn = new MY_button();
var myColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
myColorTransform.color = 0x179d20;
btn.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
```

How do i keep the white color of the  button label??

I tried, but this not seems to work

```
btn.background = true; 
    btn.backgroundColor = 0x179d20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a color transform for this - you can just change the background property.

```
var btn = new MY_button();
btn.background = 0x179d20;
```

Comment: Also tried `btn.background = true; 
 btn.backgroundColor = 0x179d20;`

Comment: Specify how you are making it red in the first place.  Is there a red rectangle you drew in it?

Comment: Yes I draw a red rectangle, and below it I draw a darker red rectangle, then made a tween to switch to those colors, I would like to accomplish this but in green, if I modify it to green then I lose the red one...  so Thats why I have been doing it with as

Comment: What if you use getChildAt() to find the rectangles and apply a colorTransform to them?